# Should updated CRLs be published even if no new certs have been revoked?

Tags: certificate-authority, certificate-revocation, crl

Should a CA publish updated CRLs even if they did not revoke any certificates? And what will happen if the latest CRL is older than what allowed in `default_crl_days` when the certificate was generated?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, CRLs must be reissued periodically in all cases. Even if no certificates were revoked. This is because CRLs have validity period with specific end of validity date determined by `Next Update` (or `NotAfter`) field. You must publish new CRL prior to that time.

If the CRL is expired, certificate chaining engine will reject that CRL and report `RevocationOffline` error.